# Says {profilePic} un-defined

Tags: undefined

VS says I have no issues but all my browsers say it is un-defined.. All input is appreciated.

````
 import React from 'react';
 import "./Post.css";
 import{Avatar} from '@material-ui/core';

 function Post({ pofilePic, image, username, timestamp,message}) {
 return (
     <div className="post">
     <div className="post__top">
     <Avatar src={profilePic}
         className="post__avatar"/>
         <div className="post__topInfo">
             <h3>{username}</h3>
             <p>Timesatmp....</p>
         </div> 
     </div>
     ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s spelled `pofilePic` in one place and `profilePic` in another.